# is there a way to update user group-inherited attributes in keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak-services

i've tried to update user group inherited   attributes(attributes inherited by users from their coresponding groups) using a user access token gained by admin with keycloak token-exchange feature but TokenAccess.setOtherClaims() does'nt change user inherited attributes